# Pawn gambits "For The Win"

Tags: pawns, terminology, gambits

Possibly confirmation bias, but I often find a game I've won involved the loss (intentional or otherwise) of a pawn, which has opened up a file for rook attack, particularly on b/g files.  Is there any catch-all term for this sort of gambit other than this title?  I wonder if anyone has statistically analysed this type of scenario.

Comment: ftw? What does that mean? Google suggests "for the win", is that what you mean?

Comment: Typically such gambits of giving the b pawn if deliberate are called wing gambits. Not necessarily to open the files for the rook but in general to open files for your pieces. Though I don't play such wing gambits so I'm not the right person to ask...

Comment: @IanBush Yes just a common net gamer term :)

Comment: This question is a bit too broad to have a definite answer, as those sacrifices may appear in many different openings and positions. You may want to enjoy this [illustrative example](https://old.chesstempo.com/gamedb/game/2146979/ply/9) by Grandmaster Alexei Shirov

Comment: If the pawn is sacrificed by advancing it until it is captured then the sacrifice might be part of a *pawn storm*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is called a [clearance sacrifice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacrifice_(chess)#Sham_sacrifices):

> In a *clearance sacrifice*, the sacrificing player aims to vacate the
> square the sacrificed piece stood on, either to open up lines for his
> own pieces, or to put another, more useful piece on the same square.

Comment: Thanks @b-swan looks like this is right. If I'm not mistaken p35 of this Swedish magazine (with front cover of a 15 year old Magnus Carlsen) has the reference https://web.archive.org/web/20120211202053/http://sjakk.no/nsf/norsk_sjakkblad/06_nr5.pdf

Comment: Google translates that reference as "Field evacuation [sic] victims constitute a thematic counterpart to magnetic victims, which was discussed in the previous chess magazine. The point here is to sacrifice a piece to use the field it was on for something more sensible."

Answer (score 4):

To mine knowledge its called "opening lines against king" in many languages this term used - no other specific name that I would have heard of in any language I know.

Answer (score 1):

No.

There is no specific word for a gambit that does that to open files to then win.

It would be the result of a general "gambit" giving up a pawn.

I note that you said lose a pawn unintentionally and then win.
That is not a gambit that is two beginners playing like beginners.